# Docker breaks libvirt bridge network

Tags: iptables, docker, bridge, ufw

This issue is driving me crazy. I run a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04, with:

- ufw to manage the firewall
- a br0 bridge
- lxd and libvirt (KVM)

I tried stock docker.io package and packages form docker's own deb repository.

I want o be able to deploy docker containers choosing the ip to bind its port (eg. -p 10.58.26.6:98800:98800) and then open the port with UFW.

But docker seems to create iptables rules that pertubates the br0 bridge (eg. host cannot ping libvirt guests)

I have looked all around and cannot find good, security aware solution.

Manually doing `iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT`seems to makes everything work.

Also setting `"iptables": false` for the docker daemon allows the bridge to behave normally, but breaks docker's containers egress network.

I have found this solution that seemed simple, by editing a single UFW's file https://stackoverflow.com/a/51741599/1091772, but it doesn't work at all.

What would be the best practice and secure way of solving this permanently, surviving to reboots ?

**EDIT:**
I ended up adding `-A ufw-before-forward -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT` at the end of `/etc/ufw/before.rules` before the COMMIT. Can I consider this as a fix or doesn't it raise some issues ?

Comment: How did that line added in the edit work out for you? Can I just do that and be done with this?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### The problem, actually a feature: [*br_netfilter*](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html)

The explanation is that the [bridge netfilter code](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/documentation/bridge-nf.html) is [enabled by Docker](https://github.com/moby/libnetwork/blob/64b7a4574d1426139437d20e81c0b6d391130ec8/drivers/bridge/bridge.go#L383) for internal container isolation: intended among other usages for stateful bridge firewalling or for leveraging *iptables*' matches and targets from bridge path without having to (or being able to) duplicate them all in *ebtables*. Quite disregarding network layering, the ethernet bridge code, at network layer 2, now makes upcalls to *iptables* working at IP level, ie network layer 3. It can be enabled only globally before [kernel 5.3](https://kernelnewbies.org/Linux_5.3#Networking) (but Docker doesn't handle the new kernel 5.3 features): either for host and every containers, or for none. Once understood what's going and knowing what to look for, adapted choices can be made.

The netfilter project describes the various [`ebtables`/`iptables` interactions](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html) when *br_netfilter* is enabled. Especially of interest is the [section 7](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7) explaining why some rules without apparent effect are sometimes needed to avoid unintended effects from the bridge path, like using:

> ```
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.1.0/24 -d 172.16.1.0/24 -j ACCEPT
> iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.16.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
> ```

to avoid two systems on the same LAN to be NATed by... the bridge (see example below).

You have a few choices to avoid your problem, but the choice you took is probably the best if you don't want to know all the details nor verify if some iptables rules (sometimes hidden in other namespaces) would be disrupted:

- permanently prevent the *br_netfilter* module to be loaded. Usually `blacklist` isn't enough, `install` must be used. This is a choice prone to issues for applications relying on *br_netfilter*: obviously Docker, Kubernetes, ...

  ```
    echo install br_netfilter /bin/true > /etc/modprobe.d/disable-br-netfilter.conf
  ```
- Have the module loaded, but disable its effects: same results with regard to Docker. For *iptables*' effects that is:

  ```
    sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
  ```

If putting this at startup, the module should be loaded first or this toggle won't exist yet.

These two previous choices will for sure disrupt *iptables* match [`-m physdev`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#physdev): The *xt_physdev* module when itself loaded, auto-loads the *br_netfilter* module (this would happen even if a rule added from a container triggered the loading). Now *br_netfilter* won't be loaded, `-m physdev` will probably never match.

- Work around br_netfilter's effect when needed, like OP: add those apparent no-op rules in various chains (PREROUTING, FORWARD, POSTROUTING) as described in [section 7](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7). For example:

  ```
    iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 172.18.0.0/16 -d 172.18.0.0/16 -j ACCEPT

    iptables -A FORWARD -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
  ```

Those rules should never match because traffic in the same IP LAN is not routed, except for some rare DNAT setups. But thanks to *br_netfilter* they do match, because they are first called for *switched* frames ("upgraded" to IP packets) traversing the *bridge*. Then they are called again for *routed* packets traversing the *router* to an unrelated interface (but won't match then).

- Don't put an IP on the bridge: put that IP on one end of a `veth` interface with its other end on the bridge: this should ensure that the bridge won't interact with routing, but that's not what are doing most container/VM common products.
- You can even hide the bridge in its own isolated network namespace (that would only be helpful if wanting to isolate from other *ebtables* rules this time).
- Switch everything to [*nftables*](https://wiki.nftables.org/wiki-nftables/index.php/Main_Page) which among stated goals will avoid these [bridge interaction issues](https://www.netdevconf.org/1.1/proceedings/papers/Bridge-filter-with-nftables.pdf). For now the bridge firewalling has no stateful support available, it's still [WIP](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/list/?series=102903&state=*) but is promised to be cleaner when available, because there won't be any "upcall".

You should search what triggers the loading of *br_netfilter* (eg: `-m physdev`) and see if you can avoid it or not, to choose how to proceed.

### Minimal Docker integration

When the breakage happens in the host initial network namespace where Docker is running rather than in a new (eg: container) network namespace, OP's rule should be added to the [`DOCKER-USER` chain](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#add-iptables-policies-before-dockers-rules) rather than alone because Docker usually inserts its own rules before what can be already found. This could even be added in some network startup script.

Here's an [idempotent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence) method for OP's case. This chain is created by Docker if it didn't exist before, so ignoring a failure makes it work wether started before or after Docker. Likewise `-I` is needed because Docker (or some versions of it) might append a dummy `-j RETURN` rule to `DOCKER-USER`, so `-I` makes it work whether started before or after Docker.

```
iptables -N DOCKER-USER 2>/dev/null || true
iptables -C DOCKER-USER -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT >/dev/null 2>&1 || 
    iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

---

### Example with network namespaces

Let's reproduce some effects using a network namespace. Note that nowhere any *ebtables* rule will be used. Also note that this example relies on the usual legacy [`iptables`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-legacy.8), not [iptables over nftables](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables/iptables-nft.8) as enabled by default on Debian buster.

Let's reproduce a simple case similar with many container usages: a router 192.168.0.1/192.0.2.100 doing NAT with two hosts behind: 192.168.0.101 and 192.168.0.102, linked with a bridge on the router. The two hosts can communicate directly on the same LAN, through the bridge.

```
#!/bin/sh

for ns in host1 host2 router; do
    ip netns del $ns 2>/dev/null || :
    ip netns add $ns
    ip -n $ns link set lo up
done

ip netns exec router sysctl -q -w net.ipv4.conf.default.forwarding=1

ip -n router link add bridge0 type bridge
ip -n router link set bridge0 up
ip -n router address add 192.168.0.1/24 dev bridge0

for i in 1 2; do
    ip -n host$i link add eth0 type veth peer netns router port$i
    ip -n host$i link set eth0 up
    ip -n host$i address add 192.168.0.10$i/24 dev eth0
    ip -n host$i route add default via 192.168.0.1
    ip -n router link set port$i up master bridge0
done

#to mimic a standard NAT router, iptables rule voluntarily made as it is to show the last "effect"
ip -n router link add name eth0 type dummy
ip -n router link set eth0 up
ip -n router address add 192.0.2.100/24 dev eth0
ip -n router route add default via 192.0.2.1
ip netns exec router iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

Let's load the kernel module *br_netfilter* (to be sure it won't be later) and disable its effects with the (not-per-namespace) toggle *bridge-nf-call-iptables*, available only in initial namespace:

```
modprobe br_netfilter
sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=0
```

Warning: again, this can disrupt *iptables* rules like [`-m physdev`](https://manpages.debian.org/iptables-extensions.8#physdev) anywhere on the host or in containers which rely on *br_netfilter* loaded and enabled.

Let's add some icmp ping traffic counters.

```
ip netns exec router iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request
ip netns exec router iptables -A FORWARD -p icmp --icmp-type echo-reply
```

Let's ping:

```
# ip netns exec host1 ping -n -c2 192.168.0.102
PING 192.168.0.102 (192.168.0.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.047 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms

--- 192.168.0.102 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1017ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.047/0.052/0.058/0.009 ms
```

The counters won't match:

```
# ip netns exec router iptables -v -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT -c 0 0
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -c 0 0
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -c 0 0
```

Let's enable *bridge-nf-call-iptables* and ping again:

```
# sysctl -w net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables=1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
# ip netns exec host1 ping -n -c2 192.168.0.102
PING 192.168.0.102 (192.168.0.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.094 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.163 ms

--- 192.168.0.102 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1006ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.094/0.128/0.163/0.036 ms
```

This time switched packets got a match in iptables' filter/FORWARD chain:

```
# ip netns exec router iptables -v -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD ACCEPT -c 4 336
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -c 2 168
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -c 2 168
```

Let's put a DROP policy (which zeroes the default counters) and try again:

```
# ip netns exec host1 ping -n -c2 192.168.0.102
PING 192.168.0.102 (192.168.0.102) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 192.168.0.102 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1008ms

# ip netns exec router iptables -v -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD DROP -c 2 168
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -c 4 336
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -c 2 168
```

The bridge code filtered the switched frames/packets via iptables. Let's add the bypass rule (which will zero again the default counters) like in OP and try again:

```
# ip netns exec router iptables -A FORWARD -i bridge0 -o bridge0 -j ACCEPT
# ip netns exec host1 ping -n -c2 192.168.0.102
PING 192.168.0.102 (192.168.0.102) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.132 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.102: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.123 ms

--- 192.168.0.102 ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1024ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.123/0.127/0.132/0.012 ms

# ip netns exec router iptables -v -S FORWARD
-P FORWARD DROP -c 0 0
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 8 -c 6 504
-A FORWARD -p icmp -m icmp --icmp-type 0 -c 4 336
-A FORWARD -i bridge0 -o bridge0 -c 4 336 -j ACCEPT
```

Let's see what is now actually received on host2 during a ping from host1:

```
# ip netns exec host2 tcpdump -l -n -s0 -i eth0 -p icmp
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
02:16:11.068795 IP 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.0.102: ICMP echo request, id 9496, seq 1, length 64
02:16:11.068817 IP 192.168.0.102 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 9496, seq 1, length 64
02:16:12.088002 IP 192.168.0.1 > 192.168.0.102: ICMP echo request, id 9496, seq 2, length 64
02:16:12.088063 IP 192.168.0.102 > 192.168.0.1: ICMP echo reply, id 9496, seq 2, length 64
```

... instead of source 192.168.0.101. The MASQUERADE rule was also called from the bridge path. To avoid this either add (as explained in [section 7](http://ebtables.netfilter.org/br_fw_ia/br_fw_ia.html#section7)'s example) an exception rule before, or state a non-bridge outgoing interface, if possible at all (now it's available you can even use `-m physdev` if it has to be a bridge...).

---

Randomly related:

LKML/netfilter-dev: [br_netfilter: enable in non-initial netns](https://lkml.org/lkml/2018/11/7/681): it would help to enable this feature per namespace rather than globally, thus limiting interactions between hosts and containers. UPDATE: added in Linux kernel 5.3, but not supported by Docker.

netfilter-dev: [netfilter: physdev: relax br_netfilter dependency](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/patch/1032397/): merely attempting to delete a non-existing *physdev* rule could create problems. (UPDATE: fixed).

netfilter-dev: [connection tracking support for bridge](https://patchwork.ozlabs.org/project/netfilter-devel/list/?series=102903&state=*): WIP bridge netfilter code to prepare stateful bridge firewalling using nftables, this time more elegantly. I think one of the last steps to get rid of iptables ('s kernel side API). UPDATE: added in kernel 5.3, but as long as there's no complete rework in Docker to use these features, doesn't change anything.

Comment: I don't mind the in-depth explanation. But I don't see actually need to do make KVM and Docker to run side-by-side without docker blocking KVM. A more copy-pasty solution would be very nice ... I'm running Ubuntu 18.04 with docker-ce 19.03.12 and qemu (1:2.11+dfsg-1ubuntu7.29)

Comment: @MadMike comprehension is half the solution.  If you don't understand how it's working, this requires one solution per configuration. Also recent kernels (5.something) have a per-namespace setting instead of a global all-namespaces-wide setting.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why a copy-pasty solution is on the "it depends" side. Seems I will need to learn about iptables if a "docker + kvm side-by-side installation" become more common on my machines :-/

Comment: FWIW, I am coming to this question from the other side, where installing QEMU broke Docker. My Docker container would no longer work in host mode but not in bridge mode. In order to address the issue, I removed QEMU and libvirt and rebooted and the bridge mode worked again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149648/discussion-between-john-smith-and-a-b).

Answer (score 5):

If the above threats not solving your problem, here's how I resolved the problem on my Debian Stretch.

- 1st, save your current iptables

  ```
  iptables-save > your-current-iptables.rules
  ```
- 2nd, delete **ALL** the Docker created rules

  ```
  iptables -D <DOCKER-CHAIN-RULES> <target-line-number>
  ```
- 3rd, add itpables rules to accept any traffic to INPUT, FORWARD and OUTPUT

  ```
  iptables -I INPUT -j ACCEPT
  iptables -I FORWARD -j ACCEPT
  iptables -I OUTPUT -j ACCEPT
  ```
- 4th, restart your Docker

  ```
  service docker restart
  ```

Once step 3 completed, you can ping your blocked libvert KVM host from another PC, you will see ICMP responses.

Restarting Docker will also add its required iptables rules back to your machine but it will not be blocking your bridged KVM  hosts any more.

If the above solution not working for you, you can restore the iptables using the following command:

- Restore iptables

  ```
  iptables-restore < your-current-iptables.rules
  ```

Comment: With Ubuntu 18.04 this works fine until the next reboot. Then you can't access KVM anymore and have to fix the iptable-rules.

Right now I'm using a `sudo iptables-save > both-work-iptables.rules` when both work and reapply them with `sudo iptables-restore < both-work-iptables.rules` after each reboot. I wish there was a more elegant solution.

Comment: Ah no. My solution doesn't work as the iptables change when docker-container change. I will delete both my comments as those don't add anything valueable to the given answer.

Comment: You have a syntax error. Debian doesn't know what `<DOCKER-CHAIN-RULES>` means. Am I missing a package that implements that or something?

Answer (score 5):

I fixed this issue by adding the following line to `/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service`:

```
[Service]
ExecStartPost=iptables -I DOCKER-USER -i br0 -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

Note that I don't have to create the chain or check the existence of this rule, because Docker always clears the existing rules first and recreates the chain before running the `ExecStartPost` command. Many thanks to excellent explanation in https://serverfault.com/a/964491/979362 to figure this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to any of startup scripts running after docker, as root:

```
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
```

If you don't want to change any startup scripts and run VMs on demand, just remember to run above command once after docker service (re)start.

Keep in mind that any VMs started before allowing network access will not have DHCP IP assigned until retry timeout or DHCP renew request.

A side effect is that all traffic will be forwarded by your host between any networks, VPNs etc - not quite a secure solution as an attacker on say VPN subnet can set your VPN IP as a gateway and probe available networks and scan.

Docker isolation should not be affected by the change.

Comment: It's funny, try as I might, while my computer is booting, I just can't see what scripts run after docker. I even squinted real hard, but no dice. I even said "Computer, tell me what scripts run after docker" a few times, but it rudely ignored me.