# qemu-kvm guest OS can access host using bridge, but cannot access other devices on same network

Tags: networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, libvirt, qemu

I want to run a qemu-kvm guest with Debian 9 as its OS on a Debian 10 host. The host is connected to the local network, and I would like the guest to be "visible" to the local network as if it were a regular device connected directly to the network. To this end, I configured a bridge named `br0` on the host by editing `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug eth0
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
    up ifconfig eth0 promisc up
    down ifconfig eth0 promisc down

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    hwaddress ether 08:60:6e:69:4a:b5
    address 192.168.1.11
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1

    bridge_ports eth0
    bridge_stp on
    bridge_fd 0
```

The MAC address configured for the bridge is the same as that of my `eth0` interface.

My host's networking seems to work fine after this change.

Using `sudo virsh edit debian9` (where `debian9` is the name of the guest), I edited the default network interface as follows:

```
    <interface type='bridge'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:bc:8c:97'/>
      <source bridge='br0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x01' slot='0x00' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Inside the guest, I assigned a static IP address by editing  `/etc/network/interfaces` as follows, as it did not seem to receive an IP address using DHCP:

```
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug enp1s0
auto enp1s0
iface enp1s0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.13
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 192.168.1.1
```

The guest seems to show up correctly in the `br0` bridge on the host when I do `sudo brctl show`:

```
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
br0             8000.08606e694ab5       yes             eth0
                                                        vnet0
docker0         8000.024202321e8f       no              veth7291e29
virbr0          8000.5254005aa541       yes             virbr0-nic
```

The host can now correctly connect to the guest (e.g., using ping or ssh), and the guest can correctly connect to the host, but other devices on the same local network cannot access the guest, or the other way around.

I suspect this must be due to some firewall/routing issue on the host, but am not sure how to diagnose this further. The following is the output of `iptables -S` on the host. I did not configure any iptables rules myself: most of them are related to libvirt's default NAT network, or a docker installation on the host:

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD DROP
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N DOCKER
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-N DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-N DOCKER-USER
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-USER
-A FORWARD -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -o docker0 -j DOCKER
-A FORWARD -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i docker0 -o docker0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER -d 172.17.0.1/32 ! -i docker0 -o docker0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8050 -j ACCEPT
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -i docker0 ! -o docker0 -j DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -o docker0 -j DROP
-A DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-2 -j RETURN
-A DOCKER-USER -j RETURN
```

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I might get the guest to become "visible" on the local network?

Comment: If you want to know why iptables (working on IP routing: layer 3) affects an Ethernet bridge (Layer 2), check there: https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because `FORWARD` chain policy is `DROP`.

You could use

```
iptables -I FORWARD -i br0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -o br0 -j ACCEPT
```

to accept all forwarded traffic from / to `br0` interface.

This is also the reason why the client does not get address via DHCP. DHCP packets from the client are dropped by the `FORWARD` policy.

Comment: This solved my problem; thanks!