# Linux bridge does not forward packets to TAP interface

Tags: networking, linux-networking, kvm-virtualization, bridge, containers

I have the following scenario where I run a Docker container which has configured inside of it a Linux bridge br0 and attached to it I have the main interface eth0 of the container and a TAP interface tap0. This last is connected to a QEMU guest machine running into the container.

The Docker container runs on a Kubernetes cluster with Calico as CNI.

The situation I have is that when I ping the IP of the container (which is assigned to the TAP interface) then I get no response.

I have then started to debug with the old mate tcpdump and I have found out that the packet arrives correctly to the eth0 of the container, they go to the bridge br0 but they do not arrive to the TAP interface tap0. For some unknown reasons, the packets are discarded.

Do you have any idea?

I have tried to disable the rf filter of the bridge but did not get to anything.

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network

Comment: If it solves your problem, it should be marked as duplicate