# Docker Compose containers cannot communicate through nftables

Tags: linux, networking, docker, routing, nftables

I just have a quick question about Docker Compose.
I have a Nftables firewall installed on my server and regarding the input and forward chain the default drop policy loaded.
Until now everything has always worked but today I wanted to install the NginX Proxy Manager, but when I log in I get a "Bad Gateway" Error. I think that the Docker-Compose containers (MySQL and Nginx) can't communicate with each other because of NFT. Without firewall everything fits. I am now wondering how to solve the problem or what nft rules I need. Below is my nft config. wg stands for WireGuard.

Thanks Jonathan :)

```
table inet basic-filter {
    chain input {
            type filter hook input priority 0; policy drop;
            ct state { established, related } accept
            iif lo accept
            ip protocol icmp accept
            ip6 nexthdr ipv6-icmp accept
            meta l4proto ipv6-icmp accept
            iif $pub_iface tcp dport 51829 accept
            iif $pub_iface udp dport $wg_port accept
            iifname $wg_iface accept
            ct state invalid drop
            reject
    }
    chain forward {
            type filter hook forward priority 0; policy drop;
            ct state { established, related } accept
            iifname $wg_iface ip saddr 10.212.0.0/16 ip daddr 10.212.0.0/16 oifname $wg_iface accept
            iifname $wg_iface oifname $pub_iface accept
            ct state invalid drop
            reject with icmpx type host-unreachable
    }
    chain postrouting {
            type nat hook postrouting priority 100; policy accept;
            iifname $wg_iface oifname $pub_iface masquerade
    }
```

Comment: Docker interferes. probable cause: https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network (yes it's about iptables but it's before all about `br_netfilter`) or (UL SE): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/719112/why-do-net-bridge-bridge-nf-call-arp-ip-ip6tables-default-to-1 .  Possible fix (on UL SE): https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/657545/nftables-whitelisting-docker/657786