# Debian not resolving mdns query

Tags: debian, avahi, mdns

Got 4 debian boxes, all suddenly not resolving mdns ip4 queries. On the contrary MacOS seems to resolve these queries just fine.

I can do `avahi-resolve --name hostname.local` and get the result 'Timeout reached'

Odly enough I can see in wireshark that the mdns queries are leaving with the responses returning i.e

```
User Datagram Protocol, Src Port: 18189, Dst Port: 5353
Multicast Domain Name System (response)
 Transaction ID: 0x0000
 Flags: 0x8400 Standard query response, No error
 Questions: 0
 Answer RRs: 1
 Authority RRs: 0
 Additional RRs: 0
 Answers
     hostname.local: type A, class IN, cache flush, addr ip-here
         Name: hostname.local
         Type: A (Host Address) (1)
         .000 0000 0000 0001 = Class: IN (0x0001)
         1... .... .... .... = Cache flush: True
         Time to live: 120 (2 minutes)
         Data length: 4
         Address: ip-here
 [Unsolicited: True]
```

All these machines have a l2 bridge: `br0` mapped to a single ethernet port, all other networking seems to work as expected (ping direct ip etc)

I'm not really sure as to why it's not resolving the query. Any help, greatly appreciated.

Update:

I've compared the difference between a working and non working mDNS response. The 4 hosts are able to resolve mDNS queries, however the 3 'servers' I am running have had docker installed and since then they respond to mDNS queries from a port other than `5353` which seems to be the only noticeable difference (other than ip/hostname/checksum).

I'll leave the question open and will answer once I've found if there's a way of getting docker to play nice with mDNS (There are questions on the internet about this)

Update2:

This issues seems to begin after a k8s installation, but only once callico networking was applied. It seems to install a lot of legacy iptables rules. I was able to get mDNS responding on the correct port by adding new iptables rules to perform SNAT when the destination port was 5353. Unfortunately calico would keep refreshing and bump this rule further down the chain stopping it from running.

I switched to flannel networking instead and deleted calico.

Comment: `all suddenly not resolving mdns` - any changes/updates done prior to this *sudden* issue?

Comment: remember that Docker affects *any* (Ethernet) bridge with (IPv4) iptables firewall rules: https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network

Comment: Alex, if you feel your answer is correct and complete, please post your answer in the answer section, and mark the Q as answered. This practice is encouraged, see https://serverfault.com/help/self-answer , this is to avoid having Q's that are not marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it's a bug in the avahi daemon.

https://github.com/lathiat/avahi/issues/448