# Docker compose gitea remote ssh connection refused

Tags: ssh, docker, docker-compose, ufw, gitea

I have setup Gitea on an Ubuntu server using this docker-compose config:

```yaml
version: '3.9'
services:
  db:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:15
    volumes:
      - 'db_data:/bitnami/postgresql'
    environment:
      - POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=gitea
      - POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=gitea
      - POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=gitea

  gitea:
    image: docker.io/bitnami/gitea:1
    volumes:
      - 'gitea_data:/bitnami/gitea'
    environment:
      - GITEA_DATABASE_HOST=db
      - GITEA_DATABASE_NAME=gitea
      - GITEA_DATABASE_USERNAME=gitea
      - GITEA_DATABASE_PASSWORD=gitea
      - GITEA_ADMIN_USER=example
      - GITEA_ADMIN_PASSWORD=example
      - GITEA_ADMIN_EMAIL=admin@example.com
      - GITEA_APP_NAME=Example Technologies
      - GITEA_DOMAIN=gitea.example.com
      - GITEA_SSH_DOMAIN=gitea.example.com
      - GITEA_SSH_PORT=22
      - GITEA_ROOT_URL=https://gitea.example.com/
      - GITEA_SMTP_ENABLED=true
      - GITEA_SMTP_HOST=smtp-relay.gmail.com:25
      - GITEA_SMTP_FROM=server@example.com
    ports:
      - '5050:3000'
      - '22:2222'

volumes:
  db_data:
  gitea_data:
```

My regular ssh service runs on port 1026, so should be no port conflicts, here is my UFW

```
status:
Status: active
Logging: on (low)
Default: deny (incoming), allow (outgoing), deny (routed)
New profiles: skip

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
80,443/tcp (Apache Full)   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
Anywhere on docker0        ALLOW IN    172.17.0.0/16             
1026/tcp                   ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
22/tcp                     ALLOW IN    Anywhere                  
80,443/tcp (Apache Full (v6)) ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
1026/tcp (v6)              ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)             
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW IN    Anywhere (v6)
```

When trying to connect from a remote machine with ssh as a test:

```
ssh git@gitea.example.com
ssh: connect to host gitea.example.com port 22: Connection refused
```

However testing locally on the server, over ssh on port 1026, I get this when executing the same command on the server:

```
ssh git@gitea.example.com
git@gitea.example.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

So I am really not sure what is going on, its like incoming remote traffic to port 22 is being blocked, but even with UFW disabled I still recieve “Connection refused” when trying to connect from a remote machine.

I have also tried using tcpdump to see what is happening but can only see that nothing responds on port 22 to the incoming packets from a remote connection, again when connecting over port 22 locally on the server running gitea, I see normal TCP traffic for initiating an SSH connection.

I have looked through IP tables and the only lines referencing port 22 I could find began with ACCEPT.

In the logs from the gitea container I can see the following indicating the SSH server is configured correctly to start on port 2222:

```
gitea-gitea-1  | 2023/05/25 09:57:29 ...s/graceful/server.go:62:NewServer() [I] [646f3109-19] Starting new SSH server: tcp::2222 on PID: 1
gitea-gitea-1  | 2023/05/25 09:57:29 cmd/web.go:220:listen() [I] [646f3109-27] Listen: http://0.0.0.0:3000
gitea-gitea-1  | 2023/05/25 09:57:29 cmd/web.go:224:listen() [I] [646f3109-27] AppURL(ROOT_URL): https://gitea.example.com/
gitea-gitea-1  | 2023/05/25 09:57:29 ...s/graceful/server.go:62:NewServer() [I] [646f3109-27] Starting new Web server: tcp:0.0.0.0:3000 on PID: 1
```

Can anyone provide any advice what might be going wrong here or how I can go about getting to the bottom of it?

Comment: Please show the output of `ss -tnlp |grep :22`

Comment: Your docker-compose.yml is working for me without modifications, I can reach the sshd on the published port.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix this with information from here: [Docker breaks libvirt bridge network](https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network)

Basically I added the following rule to ufw:

`172.20.0.2 2222/tcp        ALLOW FWD   Anywhere                   # allow gitea-gitea-1 2222/tcp gitea_default`