# Bypass nftables drop rule

Tags: firewall, nftables

**tldr;** bridge (see below) doesn't work if there is a matching drop in another table (like the default rules of firewalld).

Hello,
I'm building my own VM lib (kind of [quickemu](https://github.com/quickemu-project/quickemu)).
I have a problem with the firewall rules for bridging. I started with iptables-nft and it worked fine until I tested my scripts on fedora. No matter what I do, firewalld blocks everything. So I went with nftables to try to bypass firewalld rules directly, but even then I can't find a way to make it work without deleting firewalld rules.

It's my understanding that the priority only affects the order in which the rules are tested, if there is a drop, even at the end, the packet is dropped?

Is there a way to bypass this behavior that I don't know about? I tried looking into marks, but I'm not sure it's the right solution.

Here is the rules I use for the bridge (works perfectly is there is no other table in the ruleset):

```
#!/usr/bin/nft -f
# vim:set ts=2 sw=2 et:

table ip QEMU
delete table ip QEMU
table ip QEMU {
  chain input {
    type filter hook input priority filter - 1;

    ct state {established,related} iifname "virbr0" counter accept
  }

  chain forward {
    type filter hook forward priority filter - 1;

    ct state {established,related} iifname "virbr0" counter accept
  }

  chain postrouting {
    type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat;

    iifname "virbr0" counter masquerade
  }
}
```

Comment: You are correct: a dropped packet stays dropped, wherever and whenever it was dropped. Only an accepted packet gets the chance to be ... dropped later. When multiple firewalling tools are competing between each others, things become complicated. Note that nowhere in what you showed *bridging* (as in: forwarding Ethernet frames) is involved: it's routing over the bridge interface itself, the side that participates in routing. If now you are also running Docker or Kubernetes, then interactions between bridge firewalling and routing firewalling can also happen (making it even more difficult).

Comment: Here's how libvirt handles it: https://libvirt.org/firewall.html#firewalld-and-the-virtual-network-driver

Comment: Well that sucks.  How is that logical behavior...? What if there is another firewall in place... You really have to go through all the rules and modify them every time you need to add something like that?
Yeah I guess this is not a bridge. I have a wireless card, so I tried NAT instead (seemed simpler). I guess I got lost in my research and confused the terms.

Comment: To be a bit pedantic: the interface virbr0 is really a bridge. but the firewall you are considering is not at the bridge path, so it's not a *bridging* firewall (unless despite itself because of running Docker and loading the br_netfilter kernel module) and thus no bridging is involved (for the firewall). The fact that a Linux bridge is often involved in routing (through the interface itself rather than a bridge port) makes things confusing.

Comment: For comparison: have you ever heard of a commercial firewall applicance were two competing firewalls are working at the same time on it? This doesn't happen. There might be instances, partitioning or whatever, but if there are multiple firewall instances on it, they are made to work together. One should have a single firewall, or be ready to cope with consequences if not.

Comment: No containers in this setup, although, I would have liked to use nftables for my k8s cluster, but this will come later and I am in full control of the config, so I shouldn't have a problem here. What do you mean "not at bridge path"? I only started working with iptables, nftables and bridges a few days ago, so I'm not sure I understand everything just yet.

Comment: Better avoid mixing Docker/K8s with anything else, or be ready to cope with *more* consequences. Eg: https://serverfault.com/questions/963759/docker-breaks-libvirt-bridge-network

Comment: Ah yes, I already witnessed docker messing with my iptables config, no thanks!
And no, I don't think there is a normal system out there with multiple firewall, but you can't really know which one is active (especially if it's just custom iptables rules like I've been testing), so besides parsing the output of `nft list ruleset` or just creating custom scripts for firewalld, ufw... and ignoring the rest, I'm not really sure what to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nitpicking: despite `virbr0` being a bridge interface, this is about routing, not about bridging. The firewall happens on the routing side of the bridge: the bridge interface itself, not on the bridge ports (which would require a `table bridge` rather than a `table ip` firewall). So the word *bridging* won't be mentioned again below.

When a packet is dropped within netfilter, including *nftables*, it stays dropped. When a packet is accepted, it will then just continue to traverse additional hooks possibly making this packet dropped later, as reminded in [`nft(8)`](https://manpages.debian.org/nftables/nft.8#VERDICT_STATEMENT):

> **accept**
>
> Terminate ruleset evaluation and accept the packet. **The packet can
> still be dropped later by another hook**, for instance accept in the
> forward hook still allows one to drop the packet later in the
> postrouting hook, or another forward base chain that has a higher
> priority number and is evaluated afterwards in the processing
> pipeline.
>
> **drop**
>
> Terminate ruleset evaluation and drop the packet. **The drop occurs
> instantly**, no further chains or hooks are evaluated. **It is not
> possible to accept the packet in a later chain again**, as those are not
> evaluated anymore for the packet.

This causes firewalling tools with a default drop behavior and accepting only some flows (which is a good behavior from a security standpoint) rather than tools with a default accept behavior and dropping some flows (which is not so good from a security standpoint) to occult the decision from other firewalling tools: they drop things that other tools would have chosen to accept.

So to have two tools co-exist, actions have usually to be done on both of them.

---

For this case, one can tell *firewalld* to ignore (ie: *accept*) flows related to one or more specific interface(s), so the handling of this specific interface remains in the control of an other tool. If such handling is not done elsewhere, this can possibly open a security hole instead, so this has to be considered properly.

This answer requires *firewalld* >= 0.9.0 to leverage [*firewalld* policies](https://firewalld.org/documentation/man-pages/firewalld.policies.html) as [initially introduced](https://firewalld.org/2020/09/policy-objects-introduction#relationship-to-zones):

> Policies are applied to traffic flowing between zones in a stateful
> unidirectional manner. This allows different policies depending on the
> direction of traffic.
>
> ```
> +----------+     policyA     +----------+
> |          |  <------------  |          |
> | libvirt  |                 |  public  |
> |          |  ------------>  |          |
> +----------+     policyB     +----------+
> ```

The zone is used between a remote side and the host, policies are used for routing between zones. They will reuse interfaces attached to zones.

Create a new zone:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=local-ignore
```

Have this zone accept anything by default:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=local-ignore --set-target=ACCEPT
```

Add the target interface to this zone:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=local-ignore --add-interface=virbr0
```

This will take care of traffic between VMs and host (once rules are reloaded).

Add *firewalld* policies that will use this zone, once for ingress and once egress, with `ANY` as other side and also set them to a default behavior of `ACCEPT`:

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy=local-ignore-from
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=local-ignore-from --add-ingress-zone=local-ignore
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=local-ignore-from --add-egress-zone=ANY
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=local-ignore-from --set-target=ACCEPT

firewall-cmd --permanent --new-policy=local-ignore-to
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=local-ignore-to --add-egress-zone=local-ignore
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=local-ignore-to --add-ingress-zone=ANY
firewall-cmd --permanent --policy=local-ignore-to --set-target=ACCEPT
```

Finally reload the rules:

```
firewall-cmd --reload
```

This takes care of having traffic related to `virbr0` unhindered by *firewalld*.

Now the (huge) *nftables* table `inet firewalld` should co-exist peacefully with OP's table `ip QEMU`. Whether *firewalld* is running or not (ie: its rules are removed) should not change the behavior for anything related to `virbr0`. All restrictions have to be handled in table `ip QEMU`.

**Currently table `ip QEMU` doesn't restrict anything at all** (there is no drop rule nor drop policy) so should be fixed properly. One should not use a drop policy or this will cause again the problem that has just been fixed, in the other direction.  Just drop any unwanted traffic related to `virbr0` (especially towards `virbr0`) in it.

---

Additional interfaces can be added to the ignore list, for example to add `lxcbr0` (meaning: to leave LXC unhindered by *firewalld*):

```
firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=local-ignore --add-interface=lxcbr0
firewall-cmd --reload
```